# How do I combine 2 elements in an array together in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here I am using *css selectors* and getting values from a web site. The values are mapped into an array. I need to merge the *first element* and *second element* together. Similarly I need to map the *third and fourth elements*

This is the array which is available :

```
[ 
  'Mon',
  ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
  ' Tue',
  ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
  ' Wed',
  ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
  ' Thu',
  ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
  ' Fri',
  ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
  ' Sat',
  ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
  ' Sun',
  ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM'

]
```

Here I need to merge the **`day`** and **`timing`** into a single array element.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: (What) have you tried?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but probably the most straightforward is to use a `for` loop that increments the index by two each time.

```
var arr = [ 'Mon',
            ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
            ' Tue',
            ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
            // ...
          ];
var newArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 2) {
  newArr.push(arr[i] + arr[i + 1]);
}

console.log(newArr);
// => [ "Mon 7:30 AM to 11 PM",
//      " Tue 7:30 AM to 11 PM",
//      ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var arr = [
    ' Mon',
    ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
    ' Tue',
    ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
    ' Wed',
    ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
    ' Thu',
    ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
    ' Fri',
    ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
    ' Sat',
    ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM',
    ' Sun',
    ' 7:30 AM to 11 PM'
];

var len = arr.length;
var newArray = [];
var j = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        newArray[i] = arr[i];
    } else {
        newArray[j] += arr[i];
    }
    j++;
}

console.log(newArray);
```